# Adding node to the chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to add node having windows 10 as OS using knife bootstrap -o winrm 192.168.0.122 -x Administrator -p '' --node-name node1

But it is throwing a warning Failed to authenticate Administrator to 192.168.0.122 - trying password auth
Enter password for @ip-address. The node is basically a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Node is added automatically using `chef-client` command. In Linux it will be (as example): `chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json`

For Windows it should be a similar procedure. Note from documentation:

```
On Microsoft Windows machines: The batch file that is derived from the 
windows-chef-client-msi.erb bootstrap template executes the chef-client binary 
with a set of initial settings stored within first-boot.json on the node. 
first-boot.json is generated from the workstation as part of the initial knife 
bootstrap subcommand.
```